# Ruby using Elapsed Time to increase Obj stats

Tags: ruby, class, input, time, module

I'm still new to Ruby and I'm having some issues working with time. Essentially the goal of this project is to make a virtual pet. I have class Pet set up at that when initialized randomly generates stats for the pets hunger, energy, fun, affection, and then will determine the pets mood.

In my class Game, the user is displayed the pets current stats and then asked for input  to interact with the pet. The user input takes the string (e.g. 'Feed') and then will decrease @pet.hunger by 1.

What I want to do is create some way of storing the time elapsed since the user last interacted with a stat. If the stat has not been interacted with within 2 minutes it will be increased or decreased accordingly and the time will restart. Here is the module I attempted to use

```
module FeedTime
  def feed_time
    start_time = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
    @user_input == 'Feed'
    end_time = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
    time_elapsed = end_time - start_time
    
    @pet.hunger += 1 unless time_elapsed < 120
  end
end
```

This is how it was used within the Game class

```
require_relative 'time'
class StartGame
  include Reaction
  include FeedTime

  attr_reader :dragon

  def initialize
    @dragon = Dragon.new
  end

  def game
    feed_time
    loop do
      welcome
      user_input
      break if @user_input == 'Quit'
    end
  end
```

I've tried a few variations of this code with no luck. All of my code runs without error but Hunger will never increase.

Comment: You are setting `start_time` and `end_time` to be equal to each other. Look at your code. The logic is faulty. You set both variables at the same time. They will always be equal (by a few nanoseconds). So your 120 second difference will never trigger. Also it's better to use `Time.now`. That's a better way to get current time instead of using `Process` calls.

Comment: @Casper I think my confusion came from this article https://blog.dnsimple.com/2018/03/elapsed-time-with-ruby-the-right-way.  I assumed that the end_time would not be called until after the user input. How could I write this so that start_time and end_time allow for an elapsed time value to be created

Comment: Ben the article makes a good point. For elapsed time it seems like a better idea that way.

Comment: @Ben if you apply the article’s code, you would merely measure how long it took to gather user input. Instead, you should add another attribute to your pet, maybe `pet.last_fed_at`. Set it to the current time whenever the pet is fed.